# 5 volt GPIO pins on RPi not working?

Tags: pi-3, gpio

So, today I made a simple LED circuit with a 5 volt pin on my Pi and it doesn't work. I tried the 3 volt ones and they work, but every 5 volt pin fails to work.

The circuit just consists of a red Led, a 330 Resistor, and a couple of jumper wires.

I do remember blowing up an Led yesterday on the 5 volt current. Could that have short circuited something?

The pi works fine and raspbian seems to have no problems. Just no current from the 5 volt pin. I don't have a multi meter to confirm this though, just that the circuit doesn't work.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the Pi is still working and that at the same time there are no 5V on the respective pins. Have you checked if your LED is still okay (e.g. by putting a button cell between the legs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, After some tinkering, I figured out the problem.

Turns out I'm really dumb, and didn't realize the power railings on the side of the bread board are **split into two sections**. I only thought this was a thing for the A-E and F-J rows, so I plugged in the jumper wire to the wrong section.

But, that wasn't the source of the problem. I should've mentioned this in the original question, but I was using a breadboard connected to the pi with a breakout board. The breakout board has these metallic nibs on top which I assume is for people trying to solder? I touched the jumper wires to these nibs and still nothing happened.

Solution? I took off and put back on the ribbon cable i was using.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with the green checkmark so that people know this is solved.

Comment: I have around a dozen breadboards, but only two of them are split, so in the rare occasion I have  a problem with a circuit, it's almost always the case that I've forgotten to check if I'm using a split unit or not.